# ¿Como se cuantas posiciones ocupadas tengo en un array?

Tags: c#, array

Intento hacer lo siguiente...

```
class Nested
     {
         Persona[] Empresa;

         struct Persona
         {
             public string nombre;
             public string apellido1;
             public string apellido2;
             public Fecha fechanacimiento;
         };

         struct Fecha
         {
             public DateTime fechaNacimiento;
         };

         public Nested()
         {
             Empresa = new Persona[100];
         }

         public int Ocupados()
         {
            return Empresa.Count(s => s != null);
        }
}
```

Obtengo el siguiente error...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Son pruebas que voy haciendo, se que las List<> son mucho mejor para hacer cosas de este tipo pero no se porque no me deja comparar posiciones del array, las cuales pueden contener estructuras del tipo `Persona` con un `null`

Comment: ¿Por qué no pruebas a utilizar un [forEach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) que recorra todo el array y una variable auxiliar que vaya incrementándose si dicha posición está a `null` o no y que finalmente retorne el valor de dicha variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las estructuras son un tipo de valor que nunca pueden ser `null`. Deberías preguntarte porque estas definiendo un `struct` y no una clase y si realmente es lo que necesitas.

Definelo como una clase si quieres que pueda ser `null`.

Comment: Gracias, esto es lo que necesitaba